# Why do I get TypeError: _this.data.forEach is not a function

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, foreach

I am trying to retrieve data from the backend. These are the relevant parts of my code:

### API call

```
getData(PrimaryId:number):Observable<DataDto[]>{
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.prefix}/<xyz>/${PrimaryId}/xyz`) as Observable<DataDto[]>
}
```

### Component TypeScript

```js
onRetrieveClicked() {
  this.xyzService.getData(this.PrimaryId).subscribe(
    (xyz: DataDto[]) => {
      this.xyz = xyz
      console.log(this.xyz)
      console.log(this.xyz.forEach((data)=>data.name) 
  })
}
```

### First console.log output

```
{content: Array(1), pageable: {…}, totalPages: 1, totalElements: 1, last: true, …}
       content: Array(1)
       0: {name: max, name: null, asset: null,  …}
       length: 1
       ..........
```

But when I try to print only the name in the second console, it says that forEach is not a function. How can I solve this

**edit**
**Dto model**

```
export interface DataDto {
name: string
asset: abcDto 
status: StatusDto 
tasks: efgDto[]
nextDate: string
}
```

Comment: assumingly you want to call `forEach` for `content` which is present in your data.....

Comment: It seems like the data you get might be a plain object, not an array. It *has* some arrays as values, though.

Comment: I tried accessing it this way.       this.xyz.content.map(data=>data.name)  I get the output but also in the iDE, there is an error saying content does not exist on  type DataDto[]

Comment: `xyz: DataDto[]` is misleading the TS compiler. If you are indeed getting a plain object at runtime, then TS doesn't know that, it *thinks* you are getting an array but it can only check that at compile time.

Comment: Check my answer, it explains entirely what's going on here, and how to fix it using Angular preferred operations.

Comment: Can you please post your DataDto model?

Comment: added the dto model

Comment: its really strange, model that you mention is totally different from what you are receiving in response. In that case how response will convert to model?

Comment: I think there's already a lot of answer to your question, you should accept one. Both Diego and mine's answers fully answer the question asked here. The fact that the 2nd console.log returns undefined is because Array.forEach doesn't return a value, you need Array.map for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `xyz` variable that you type as `DataDto[]`, an array, is actually an object. This can be seen in your `console.log`, an array would be enclosed in [], not {}

```
is an object --> {
  content: Array(1), pageable: {…}, totalPages: 1, totalElements: 1, last: true, …}
       content: Array(1)
       0: {name: max, name: null, asset: null,  …}
       length: 1
 }
```

The data you are looking for is most likely the response object's `content` so add an import for `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';` and transform the data you've gotten from the response:

```js
this.xyzService.getData(this.PrimaryId).pipe(
  map((xyzResponse: any) => xyzResponse.content)
).subscribe(
  (xyz: DataDto[]) => {
    this.xyz = xyz;
    console.log(this.xyz);
    let dataNames = xyz.map(data => data.name);
    console.log(dataNames);
}
```

I've typed xyzResponse as `any` but you could ofcourse create a reusable type for it if the API always returns the object with content, pageable, totalPages, ...

Rxjs is the library that Angular uses to handle asynchronous programming, such as HTTP calls or component events. Rxjs chains asynchronous manipulations together in a pipe (hence the `.pipe` call). Inside of this pipe rxjs expects a chain of operators that will perform operations on the asynchronous data, one by one. The `map` operator takes the input value and returns a new value so that the value you subscribe to has been transformed from the HTTP response to the `.content` field of the HTTP response.

Working in this way fixes all TypeScript compiler errors and allows you to chain additional calls later, like retrying if the API times out, or catching errors, or merging in other HTTP calls.

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: What does? The 2nd console.log? That's your code, but yea it'll print that, because forEach doesn't return a value :p

Comment: If you want to see each data.name use this: `this.xyz.forEach((data)=>{console.log(data.name)})`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `this.xyz` is not an array, but has an array property called `content`, you should modify your response object in order to accept it.

You can check if your objects are arrays with the following method

```
Array.isArray(obj)
```

Update your code to this.

```
this.xyzService.getData(this.PrimaryId).subscribe(
  (xyz: NewObject) => {
    this.xyz = xyz
    console.log(this.xyz)
    //If you have doubts of what is comming is nice to check if your property is an array
    if(Array.isArray(this.xhy.content) {
        console.log(this.xyz.content.forEach((data)=>data.name) });
    }
}
```

Create a new object in order to support your response

```
class NewObject {
    content: Array<DataDto>
    // other values here
}
```

Another approach is like @Robin says in the comment

```
this.xyzService.getData(this.PrimaryId).subscribe((xyz: {content: DataDto[]}) => 
        {
        this.xyz = xyz
        console.log(this.xyz)
        //If you have doubts of what is comming is nice to check if your property is an array
        if(Array.isArray(this.xhy.content) {
            console.log(this.xyz.content.forEach((data)=>data.name) });
        }
    }
```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'DataDto[]

Comment: Well if you wanna cut corners you could just do: `.subscribe((xyz: {content: DataDto[]}) => {console.log(xyz.content.forEach((data)=>data.name))})`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to loop through an object instead of array
I think you can try this:

```
console.log(this.xyz.content.forEach((data)=>data.name) })
```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'DataDto[]